# What do I get experience from?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed in the after game screens, different things will give you experience. What are the different things that can give you experience, and how much experience do they give you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the a list things you can earn XP from and how much XP they grant.

**Time XP** (Earned based on the time spend in a match.)

- 3.4 XP per sec

**Medal XP** (Bonus XP based on your highest medal achieved.)

- Gold : 150 XP
- Silver : 100 XP
- Bronze : 50 XP

**Match Finished XP** (Bonus XP for finishing a match.)

- 250 XP

**Win XP** (Bonus XP for winning a match.)

- 500 XP

**Consecutive Match XP** (Bonus XP if you didn't leave matchmaking between matches.)

- 200 XP

**Backfill XP** (Bonus XP if you were put in a match currently in progress.)

- 400 XP

**First Win of the Day XP** (Bonus XP for your first win of the day.)

- 1500 XP

**Group Bonus XP**  (Bonus % if you are in a group)

- 20% XP

**Leaver Penalty** (Penalty for leaving too many games in a certain amount of time)

- (-75)% XP

[Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1540919396)

Comment: Maybe a note about the exp penalty for leaving too many games.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer done

Comment: @Dragonrage Is the leaver penalty a -75%, or a -25%?

Comment: @Unionhawk -75%

Comment: I haven't gotten backfill since the actual launch of the game, but I saw it in the beta. I've definitely joined games in progress. Do you know if there are more specific criteria for that one?

Comment: @StrixVaria it may be bugged, I have heard a number of people saying that they have received it as recent as a few days ago, but I have also heard a lot of people complaining they weren't getting it.

Comment: Those medal bonuses don't look right to me.  I thought it was 80, 160, 240.

Comment: @MBraedley i got a gold medal last night that gave me 150. i can double check though when I play tonight

Comment: I don't like the Time XP because it basically means that you get punished for winning quickly.

Comment: @Exa Considering the Win XP, I'd say it punishes you a lot more for losing quickly.

Comment: @MBraedley 50/100/150 is correct. If you've seen different (likely 60/120/180), it's because of the Group Bonus.

Comment: Also to shed some light on the Leaver's Penalty- the penalty is granted if your matches played vs matches completed (MPvMC) ratio drops below a certain threshold, and persists until the ratio climbs above that ratio again. The MPvMC ratio is calculated off your last 20 matches.