# How is EXP Gain from Medals Calculated?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, a player can be issued medals for peak performance in 4 categories; Eliminations, Damage, Healing, and Objective Time, and Objective Kills. Bronze, Silver, and Gold medals are awarded for 3rd, 2nd, and 1st in that category, respectively.

How is EXP gain calculated from these medals? What are the specific EXP numbers gained from the different categories of medals? **Will multiple Gold medals stack their EXP? Can EXP from multiple categories of medals stack, or is only the highest achieved counted?**

*All this time playing the game, and I still don't know how medals work...*

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I did see this question, but I think mine is different enough to warrant this post. I wasn't sure how the medal earnings would stack with each other, how the EXP is awarded from multiple categories, etc.

Comment: But that is all asked in the other question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer No, it isn't. I've read through the entire post, and I don't see anywhere that my specific requests were asked or answered.

Comment: "how much experience do they reward?". If the answer doesn't exhaustively explain that, it needs to be edited. There's no need for this question.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The parts I've highlighted are what's missing from the question you've linked. The information in Riley's answer is also not present in the linked question.

Comment: I don't like it when people reply to me without even reading what I said. Good day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46741/discussion-between-kaizerwolf-and-danmakugrazer).

Comment: The missing info was added to the other answer, and was present in comments since June.

Comment: "Worth adding that the rewards are not cumulative, you get whichever is highest. For example, if you get three gold medals, you get 150 exp, not 450"

Comment: @DCShannon And I've read time and time again that comments are not part of the answer. Everyone is throwing conflicting information at me, and from what I've learned about this site, that was the rule concerning comments. I didn't pay attention to them while reading through the linked question and answer, because of that.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer And that's also great, let's just edit the answers over there, when the question didn't specifically ask for it, to answer my question here. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf It's my understanding that the comments aren't part of the answer for voting purposes. That doesn't mean the information isn't there for you to read, especially when it has multiple upvotes. The question does specifically ask for this information: "how much experience do they reward?". And yes, that *is* great that the answer was edited to be clearer.

Comment: When an edit solves another question, imo, edit the current answer/question, don't make another one.

Comment: @Karlyr I don't have the rights nor the intention of editing another question.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Just editing the answer was enough. It was solving both "problems". And just wait until the question is peer reviewed if you want to edit it. No need to stress about it...

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269531/what-do-i-get-experience-from

Answer (score 3):

The experience granted for medals only counts the highest quality medal received, and is applied only once no matter how many medal received. For example: if a player has two gold medals and one silver medal, only 150 XP is received for one gold medal.

- Gold Medal: 150 XP
- Silver Medal: 100 XP
- Bronze Medal: 50 XP

From: http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Progression